# ToolTipService Options in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, tooltip

I need to use TooltipService's options in silverlight 5:

```
ShowDuration

InitialShowDelay
```

I tried to define them But it's impossible in silverlight...

I know about the advance DLL but it not good for me...

How can i define those options?

Thanks

Comment: I think they only work in WPF, and not in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

The properties are you talking about are not present in the silverlight implementation of the `TooltipService`.

You need at least to extend `TooltipService` and implement such functionalities by yourself.